# How to get values from models using foreign key in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, model, grails-orm

I am using two models like Journal and Volume... Volume contains foreign key of Journal, ie Journal_id ... Now i want to get datas from volumes where Journal_id=1 .... Could someone help me with this please...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a proxy Journal item using the [`load`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html) method and use that in a query.  That'll prevent actually loading the Journal item that you have the ID for, but will do the query that you want to return the Volumes:

```
def findAllVolumesFor(Long journalId) {
    Journal journal = Journal.load(journalId)
    return Volume.findAllByJournal(journal)
}
```